# thymeleaf <div th:each....> disappears after refreshing page

Tags: html, thymeleaf

This is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
 <head>
   <meta charset="EUC-KR">
      <title>Taco cloud</title>
 </head>
 <body>
   <h1>Designate your taco!</h1>
   <img th:src="@{/images/TacoCloud.png}">  

   <form method="POST" th:object="${taco}">
     <div class="grid">     
       <div class="ingredient-group" id="wraps">

         <h3>Designate your taco!</h3>

         <div th:each="ingredient:${wrap}">
           <input type="checkbox" value="${ingredient.id}"/>
           <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span>
         </div>
        
       </div>
     </div>         
     <button>Submit your taco</button>
   </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

When I press the `Submit your taco` button, my controller returns this html file back with

```java
        return "design";
```

But the problem is after the controller runs `return "design"`,
the following part disappears:

```
        <div th:each="ingredient:${wrap}">
            <input type="checkbox" value="${ingredient.id}"/>
            <span th:text="${ingredient.name}">INGREDIENT</span>
        </div>
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: I'm guessing you should do a `redirect:` to design, rather than a return to design.  If you are returning design, you probably aren't adding the ingredients to the model like you are on the GET controller method.

Comment: Can you add the code of your `@GetMapping` and `@PostMapping` methods from your controller to the question?